# Confusion about $\{f\in C[0,1]|f(0)=0\}$ being closed in $(C[0,1],||\cdot||_\infty)$ but not closed in $(C[0,1],||\cdot||_1) $.

Tags: functional-analysis, vector-spaces, proof-writing, normed-spaces

I am not sure as to why $Y=\{f\in C[0,1]|f(0)=0\}$ is closed with respect to the infinity norm but not the $L^1$ norm. I tried to use a counter example $f_n(t)=1-e^{-nt}$, by trying to show that the limit function is not in $Y$ but isn't the fact that $f(0)\neq 0$ mean that the limit is not in $Y$ even though $f_n\in Y$?

I have probably contradicted myself, but I have no idea as to how to attempt this any other way and would be grateful for any help!

Comment: It is unclear what specifically are you asking. Indeed, the limit of this sequence in the $||\cdot ||_1$ norm is the constant function $1$, which is not in $Y$. This shows that $Y$ is not closed.

Comment: @Mark apologies for my question being unclear, I have only just started studying functional analysis so I my understanding is flawed and shallow. So would $f_n(t)=1-e^{-nt}$ have the same limit in the $||\cdot||_\infty$? If not why?

Comment: No, it wouldn't. Convergence in $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ is uniform convergence, and your sequence doesn't converge uniformly. If we assume $f_n$ converges uniformly to some function $f$, then in particular $f_n(t)\to f(t)$ for all $t\in [0,1]$, and so we must have $f(0)=0$, and $f(t)=1$ for $t\in (0,1]$. But it is a standard result that a sequence of continuous function can't converge uniformly to a non-continuous function. So we have a contradiction.

Comment: @Mark forgive me if anything I ask is incorrect or simple, but does that mean that the limit function is piecewise and why have you used a semiopen interval?

Comment: What I said is that if $f_n$ had a limit $f$ in the $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ norm then we would have $f_n(t)\to f(t)$ for all $t$, and so $f(t)=\lim\limits_{n\to\infty} (1-e^{-nt})=\begin{cases}
0, & t=0 \\ 
1, & t>0
\end{cases}$.

Comment: @Mark thanks for clearing that up, the more I think about it the more it makes sense but why couldn't the piecewise function be the limit in the $||\cdot||_1$ norm?

Comment: The piecewise function is not continuous, so it doesn't belong to the space $C[0,1]$ at all. If we looked at a larger space then it would be true that $f_n$ converges to this $f$ in the $||\cdot ||_1$ norm (not in the $||\cdot ||_{\infty}$ norm, as I explained), but in $C[0,1]$ it is irrelevant. The only limit of $f_n$ in $C[0,1]$ is the constant function $1$.